# Bug in Odoo gamification addon

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

When I create a goal definition with:
computation mode : (Automatic: sum on a field,
Model : Sale Order Line,
Field to Sum : SubTotal)

When I add this goal definition to a challenge and try to start it, I get this traceback:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)

Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/gamification/plan.py", line 342, in action_start
    return self.generate_goals_from_plan(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/gamification/plan.py", line 439, in generate_goals_from_plan
    goal_obj.update(cr, uid, [new_goal_id], context=context)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/gamification/goal.py", line 278, in update
    new_value = res and res[0][field_name] or 0.0
KeyError: u'price_subtotal'
```

this is a video that shows the scenario that I did: http://youtu.be/b546xTc1ArY

Comment: Odoo is not a bug tracker for a particular piece of software. Please [report the issue directly to Odoo](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues).

Comment: I obviously meant to write "StackOverflow is not a bug tracker for a particular piece of software..."

Comment: I used the word "bug" in my question, but in fact, I'm not 100% sure that it is a bug or a bad manipulation from me, that's why I put it here.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are writing code, you are just using the software, so this doesn't sound like a StackOfverflow question...

Comment: But since it's an opensource software, I can change code according to my needs, Anyway, I guess you have more experience than me in this website, so I respecte your opinion.